# Using Types to Designing Domain

Tags: f#, mongodb

I am trying to model a domain of metrics for use in a BI application.  I recently read the [Designing with Types](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-intro/) series, and felt that it could be useful, so I wanted to give it a try.  What I'm not sure is if I'm trying too hard....

1. The metrics are application-defined, meaning they are finite and won't change during runtime.  A dozen metrics would probably be a lot.
2. New metrics will be introduced as the application grows
3. A user will be selecting which metrics they want to use, and the application has to take that and go "do stuff", like building a query to the backend store (MongoDB, in this case).
4. There may be application logic associated with metrics that I would like enforced through pattern matching so that when I introduce a new metric, I want the compiler to tell me that I need to do some work.

Here's what I have:

```
type Metrics =
  | Revenue
  | Volume
  | PriceAsp
  with
    member m.FormatGroupings =
      match m with
        | Revenue -> [("revenue", """$sum: { "$Amount" }" """)]
        | Volume  -> [("volume", """$sum: { "$Quantity" }" """)]
        | PriceAsp -> List.append Revenue.FormatGroupings Volume.FormatGroupings

    member m.FormatProjections =
      match m with
        | Revenue -> [("revenue", "$revenue")]
        | Volume -> [("volume", "$volume")]
        | PriceAsp -> [("priceAsp", """ $divide: ["$revenue", "$volume"]  """)]


let buildQuery groupBy (metrics:Metrics list) =
  let concatenate f =
    let x = metrics
            |> List.collect f
            |> List.map (fun m -> sprintf "{%s: %s}" (fst m) (snd m) )
    System.String.Join(",", x)

  let groupings = concatenate (fun m -> m.FormatGroupings)
  let projections = concatenate (fun m -> m.FormatProjections)

  sprintf """{$group: {_id: {%s: "$%s"}}, %s}, $project: {%s}}""" groupBy groupBy groupings projections
```

With examples of usage:

```
buildQuery "foo" [Revenue; Volume]  //Simple
buildQuery "foo" [PriceAsp]         //Compound
```

Note that `PriceAsp` is "made up of" both `Revenue` and `Volume`.

Please provide any general comments.  Some specific questions I have are:

1. Have the business rules for the metric calculations be embedded within the types
2. Show that some metrics are built off of other metrics (for example, `PriceAsp`), and enforce the explicit relationship.  Above, we see that `PriceAsp` is made up of `Revenue` and `Volume` because it's in that list.  But it would be better to make it enforced explicitly through typing.
3. There are formatting rules around an "instance" of a specific metric.  For example, when Revenue is shown to a user, it should be rounded to the nearest whole dollar, with thousand separators and a currency symbol (ex:  $1,234,567).
4. Is there an elegant way (using `List.fold`, perhaps) for doing what String.Join does?  String.Join is just so convenient...

A base metric would look like this (no `$project`):

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      foo: "$Foo"
    },
    revenue: { $sum: "$Amount" }
  }
}
```

A compound metric may look like this:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      foo: "$Foo"
    },
    revenue: { $sum: "$Amount" },
    volume: { $sum: "$Quantity" }
  },
  $project: {
    priceAsp: { $divide: ["$revenue", "$volume"] }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have only a limited number of metric types?

In which case, you might want to make a union case of the possible types.
The compound cases can be recursive, referring to the type.

```
type Metric = 
    | Revenue of string * string 
    | Volume  of string * string
    | Compound  of string * Metric list
```

Then your `formatMetric` function needs to handle each case separately

```
let formatMetric metric =
    match metric with
    | Revenue (label,formula) -> 
        sprintf "%s: {%s}" label formula
    | Volume  (label,formula) -> 
        sprintf "%s: {%s}" label formula
    | Compound (label,metrics) -> 
        sprintf "%s: {%s}" label "other metrics"
```

Note that that if you use this approach you don't really need the label any more, as the cases *are* the label.

```
type Metric = 
    | Revenue of string 
    | Volume  of string
    | Compound  of Metric list
```

And then you could also make `formatMetric` recursive, printing all the child formulas for a compound formula

```
let rec formatMetric metric =
    match metric with
    | Revenue formula -> 
        sprintf "Revenue={%s}" formula
    | Volume  formula -> 
        sprintf "Volume={%s}" formula
    | Compound metrics -> 
        let childFormats = 
            metrics 
            |> List.map formatMetric
            |> List.reduce (+) 
        sprintf "Compound: {%s}" childFormats
```

The formatting is not exactly what you want, but I'm sure you get the general idea.

#### EDIT

**General Comment**

Personally, I wouldn't add those member functions to the type. I would focus on designing the types in their own module independent of any particular representation, and then have a *separate* module that mapped them into the appropriate representation for MongoDB.  That way you are not mixing up different requirements.

**String join.**

A simple string join is trivial to write:

```
let stringJoin sep list :string = 
    let append s t = s + sep + t
    list |> List.reduce append

stringJoin ", " ["a"; "b"; "c"; ]
```

**Separate the types from the representation**

But if you separate the types from the representation, you may find that you naturally create MongoDB specific functions that generate the appropriate representation. The idea is to build up a mini-language that you can compose together to make bigger blocks.
I don't know the MongoDB syntax, but maybe something like this?

```
let mSum p = sprintf "{ $sum: ""%s"" }" p
let mDivide p q = sprintf "{ $divide: [""%s"", ""%s""] }" p q
let mLabel p q = sprintf "%s : %s" s
let mGroup id ps = sprintf "$group: { %s, %s }" id (stringJoin ", " ps)
let mProject p q = sprintf "$project: { %s }" (stringJoin ", " ps)
```

If you are doing a lot of this, you might be better off using a JSON library. In which case the workflow would be:

```
domain type ==>  convert to intermediate type for Mongo API ==> convert to JSON
```

Comment: This is more inline with my original thinking.  I think the article I linked to in the original question made my try too hard.  I edited the question with this updated code.  I would be interested in your feedback on that.  thanks

Comment: I really like the thought behind this answer.  Distilling the types down to "regular" and "compound" is good.  Regarding my question #2, could I do `PriceAsp of [Revenue;Volume]`?  The separation of building the query from the type makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your types, I think that simple metrics and compound metrics should have their own types, to enforce their requirements and to avoid repeating yourself. One way to do that is to define `Metric` as:

```
type Metric =
  | SimpleMetric of SimpleMetric
  | CompoundMetric of CompoundMetric
```

Here, `SimpleMetric` and `CompoundMetric` are separate discriminated unions, and both of them have members specific to their case.

The whole code could look like this:

```
type SimpleMetric =
  | Revenue
  | Volume
  with
    member m.Name =
        match m with
          | Revenue -> "revenue"
          | Volume -> "volume"

    member m.Grouping =
        match m with
          | Revenue -> """$sum: { "$Amount" }" """
          | Volume -> """$sum: { "$Quantity" }" """

    member m.Projection =
        "$" + m.Name

type CompoundMetric =
  | PriceAsp
  with
    member m.Name =
        match m with
          | PriceAsp -> "priceAsp"

    member m.Metrics =
        match m with
          | PriceAsp -> [SimpleMetric Revenue; SimpleMetric Volume]

    member m.Projection =
        match m with
          | PriceAsp -> """ $divide: ["$revenue", "$volume"]  """
// CompoundMetric references Metric, so the two types have to be declared together
and Metric =
  | SimpleMetric of SimpleMetric
  | CompoundMetric of CompoundMetric
  with
    member m.Name =
        match m with
            | SimpleMetric sm -> sm.Name
            | CompoundMetric cm -> cm.Name

    member m.Projection =
        match m with
            | SimpleMetric sm -> sm.Projection
            | CompoundMetric cm -> cm.Projection

    member m.FormatGroupings =
      match m with
        | SimpleMetric sm -> [(sm.Name,sm.Grouping)]
        | CompoundMetric cm -> cm.Metrics |> List.collect (fun m -> m.FormatGroupings)

    member m.FormatProjections = [(m.Name, m.Projection)]

let buildQuery groupBy (metric:Metric list) =
  let concatenate f =
    let x = metric
            |> List.collect f
            |> List.map (fun (name, value) -> sprintf "{%s: %s}" name value)
    System.String.Join(",", x)

  let groupings = concatenate (fun m -> m.FormatGroupings)
  let projections = concatenate (fun m -> m.FormatProjections)

  sprintf """{$group: {_id: {%s: "$%s"}}, %s}, $project: {%s}}""" groupBy groupBy groupings projections
```

Usage:

```
buildQuery "foo" [SimpleMetric Revenue; SimpleMetric Volume]
buildQuery "foo" [CompoundMetric PriceAsp]
```

The whole code is longer than your version, but I think adding new metrics will be easier this way.

Also, I don't like that I have to define `Name` and `Projection` in `Metric`, but I don't see a way around that.

Now, to your questions:

> Any general comments?

I think the type shouldn't be called `Metrics`, it should be `Metric`, because a value of that type defines a single metric, not some collection.

Also, your `concatenate` function can be simplified by using pattern matching instead of `fst` and `snd` (see the above code).

> Is there an elegant way for doing what `String.Join` does?

I don't think so. There is a [`String` module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353758.aspx), but it doesn't have anything like `Join`. (And its documentation specifically refers methods of the `System.String` type.)

Comment: I like the distinction between Simple and Compound.  Good point on the `concatenate` - much more readable.  If the formatting for the query were separate from the types, like @Grundoon suggests, then maybe `Name` and `Projection` go away.  I think what I'm struggling with now is if all the operations should be with the type, or separated out in other modules.